# rails, preview button in form question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to set up a preview button in an edit form based on the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/38-multibutton-form) by Ryan Bates. There are two buttons [edit] and [update].

When the user clicks the preview button, the "update" function in the controller is called. If I simply set the @article variable based on a find of the article table (as per below controller) the preview button resets the values in the form to the saved data and I lose my edits.

Is there a way I can have a preview mode for updates? New works fine, only edit has this issue.

```
  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if params[:preview_button] || !@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      render :action => 'edit'
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully updated.') }
      end
    end
  end
```

Edit: I tried using the below code instead

```
if params[:preview_button] || !@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
  @article = Article.new(params[:article])
  render :action => 'edit'
else
```

Which preserves the data, however there's a side-effect. Clicking the preview button from [http://localhost:3000/articles/4/edit] redirects to [http://localhost:3000/articles/4] clicking again here goes to the new view [http://localhost:3000/articles].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if params[:preview_button] || !@article.update_attributes(params[:article])
```

Only in the case of the preview_button param not existing is the article being updated.

You want something like:

```
@article.attributes = params[:article]
if params[:preview_button] or !@article.save
  render :action => 'edit
```

Comment: Be very, very careful with mixing `||` and `or`. In Ruby, they are not the same thing.